# Human science and contasting perspectives

Tags: knowledge

In my lecture notes on introduction to philosophy, my professor asked us some questions in class last semester, and I was so confused even till now. So I want to hear some perspectives in this forum on how the health of a discipline is brought up by contrasting perspectives in the area of political sciences?

Question 1: how would contrasting perspectives in the political sciences help nurture the health of the discipline?

Question 2: How would contrasting perspectives hinder the health of a discipline in the political sciences?

I just cannot possibly think of a way how they can be related, I would appreciate some good real life examples to help me understand these two questions.

Comment: I think Politics SE might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Extreme example: in totalitarian Soviet Russia, Stalin's word was absolute.  He allowed no contrasting perspectives with regard to his pronouncements, and so the flourishing of his country was hobbled by false ideas.